# Suggestions for allowing ad-hoc queries against postgresql via simple web service

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3 two node cluster with warm-standby (read-only) slave.  There are around 30 individual databases with a few hundred total tables and 1.3 TB of raw data.  I'd really like the internets to have full access to these tables and allow folks to write arbitrary queries against.  The main reason is my ignorance and incompetence with setting up useful things like REST services, etc...

So I suppose one approach would be to simply allow postgresql tcp connections to the warm-standby host as a user with very limited SELECT perms and perhaps that is what I should do?

Another approach would be to have some simple JSON(P) emitting service that simply takes a database and query string, then returns results?

And I suspect you'll have a better approach, so that's why I am here :)

In general, I am not worried if the internets overrun this host with load and DOS's it.  I just don't want it to become a security liability or have some method to delete data on the warm-standby host.  The machine would be there for use and if there are naughty users, too bad for the others I guess. If it gets popular, I could setup more readonly hosts, anyway...

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and for those that say I just need to grit my teeth and figure out how to properly provide web services for the data.  My main languages are PHP and python, so if you have ideas of tools for those languages...

Comment: Check out PostgreSQL Studio: http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/about/features/index.html or TeamPostgreSQL: http://www.teampostgresql.com/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

There is a site: [`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that allows simple querying of different databases. Its code is open sourced and available on github [`here`](https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle).

You can try to adapt the code to your needs.